# Woocommerce cart table too wide

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am developing a custom theme from scratch and I am using woocommerce to build the shop. The problem is that on the cart page, the cart table ( with all the products added to cart) is too wide and is scrollable. The product images are small but each column is very wide. I tried it on several different themes and the result is the same. I might be wrong but I don't think that this it the default behaviour of it. I want to make it fit the screen without being scrollable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see if default Woocommerce. To override the cart page, copy the WooCommerce template file to your theme like so:

```
woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php   
to --> yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart.php
```

and modify it in your theme.

Comment: Alright thanks a lot! I did that but I didn't know whether this is how the cart table should be displayed or not. I guess I have to play with the code a bit

Comment: It is in the woocommerce plugin so it can be considered as default I believe.